# CMD BAT - Erorrlevel qwirk

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

One of our scripts executes this code however ERRORLEVEL should not have been set:

```
@IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO Error %ERRORLEVEL%: Something not set
EXIT /B 1
```

So I added `SET ERRORLEVEL=` before it and it still fired. A number of web articles reference to NOT do `SET ERRORLEVEL=0` as `%ERRORLEVEL%` and `ERRORLEVEL` have different behaviours. So in a sample simple BAT, the code performs correctly. But in the more complex code with multiple levels of BATs it does not.

Has anyone come across this and know what might be going on?

After reading [about the exit codes](http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-3-return-codes.html) I revised the logic to

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  ECHO Error %ERRORLEVEL%  After ERRORLEVEL
  REM take some action
)
```

Is this the best way to handle ERRORLEVEL?

Comment: Both methods are okay. There's probably something else wrong in the rest of the code. BTW to clear the errorlevel use `ver>nul`.

Comment: We'd need a greater amount of code to analyse your problem. I rarely use `%errorlevel%` since its behaviour can be position-dependent. I use `if errorlevel n` meaning 'if errorlevel is **n or greater than n**.

Comment: When using `%ERRORLEVEL%` withing a block defined by `(` and `)` be aware of [delayed expansion trap](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Run in a command prompt window `set /?` and read the output help completely. Better for checking exit codes is the method described by Microsoft in support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69576).

Comment: (me GMT+11) Ok I tried all variants on SETLOCAL and no SETLOCAL, same deal "Set ERRORLEVEL=" did not clear it, however the suggestion to do "ver>nul" did. Something twilight zone wise is going on. Full disclosure BAT being called from powershell so I need to check if LEVEL somehow passed through on the cmd.exe /c call... Anyway with the "ver>nul" working, I have a way forward. thanks (p.s. how to I tick a comment as an answer?)